# Remove the distance between count and capacity in List

Tags: c#

I've created a list and assign value to list.

```
List<int> array = Enumerable.Repeat(0, max).ToList();
```

The final output is correct. But the two criteria from List (count and capacity) are different from each other.

For ex : capacity is : 2048 and count is : 1559. why?

How to remove this distance?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the distance"?  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @David it sounds like he doesn't want the capacity to be higher than the count, but no clue why you would even consider removing it

Comment: Capacity is the memory allocated for the list to be used and not exactly how many items are there in the list. It's not something that can be changed, at least not easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to Bursac Milan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291872/797882) for explanation.

For this question:

> How to remove this distance?

You can fix the capacity by creating your own list with a initial capacity like below:

```
var list = new List<int>(max);
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, max));
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/D4pU3X)

Answer (score 3):

Capacity is the number of elements that the List can store before resizing is required, whereas Count is the number of elements that are actually in the List.

Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to use is [`TrimExcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sets the capacity to the actual number of elements in the List, if that number is less than a threshold value.
>
> This method can be used to minimize a collection's memory overhead if no new elements will be added to the collection. The cost of reallocating and copying a large List can be considerable, however, so the TrimExcess method does nothing if the list is at more than 90 percent of capacity. This avoids incurring a large reallocation cost for a relatively small gain.

Answer (score 0):

This is due the way `List<T>` is implemented. Watering down the whole thing, `List<T>` has a private array variable that holds all the items you add. Now, arrays are fixed in size. So, MS started off with minimum size as 4. This is what your initial array size is. So, following line of code internally creates an array of size 4.

```
List<int> test = new List<int>();
// internally
int[] _items = new int[4];
```

When we start adding items, List class internally calculates whether its internal array is big enough or not. When in the list above, 5th element is added, it can obviously not store it in the array. So, it creates a new array and copies everything there. The new array size is decided based on a private method in `List<T>` class called `EnsureCapacity`. Class sends it `current array size + 1` which will be 5 in this case. This method then internally doubles the number and creates a new array. So a new array with size of 8 will be created. On 9th item, it becomes 16 and so on.

This will continue until we hit the 2GB mark (max object size in .Net).

While there is no harm in having higher capacity than the size of list, but if you are working on memory sensitive application, you can call `TrimExcess` (it is expensive) when you are sure that no new items will be added. Alternatively, use the constructor where you set the capacity yourself.

One thing which is baffling for me is that `ToList` extension method calls the `List<T>` constructor with `IEnumerable<T>` as argument. This constructor claims that capacity will be same as size of collection given but somehow that is not the case.